custom neural network implementation is giving 10% accuracy on mnist dataset
I've created a toy neural network in python for learning purposes and decided to test it on mnist dataset, I didn't expect great results but the result that I got - 10% is as good as a guess. For many days I've tried to debug it, I changed the learning rate, epochs, batching, the architecture, and other parameters as well but I couldn't find the issue which led me to think that the problem might be more fundamental, maybe in implementation.
The neural network is an mlp with a softmax activation in the last layer and it's using cross-entropy loss function. There are 2 hidden layers, each 64 neurons, the input layer has 784 neurons.
My guess is there should be an issue with the weights and biases since that's what is used for predictions, however, I couldn't find a bug in any calculation.
This is the NN class
class NN:

    def __init__(self):
        self.weights = []

    def forward(self, x: np.ndarray, w: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, activation=None):
        """
        Computes forward pass for a fully connected layer
        if activation function is provided it will be applied

        Parameters:
        - x: A numpy ndarray(1 x n), activations of previous layer
        - w: A numpy ndarray, weights connecting this layer to the next layer
        - b: A numpy ndarray(1 x n), bias for the layer

        Returns:
        - nd numpy array(1 x m)
        """

        forward_x = x.dot(w).reshape(1, -1) + b
        activated_x = self.relu_activation(forward_x)

        return forward_x, activated_x


    def backward(
        self,
        dprev: np.ndarray,
        activated: np.ndarray,
        unactivated: np.ndarray,
        w: np.ndarray,
    ):
        """
        Computes backward pass for a fully connected layer

        Parameters:
        - dprev: A numpy nd array of previous gradient(1 x n)
        - activated: A numpy nd array of layer with activated values(1 x m)
        - unactivated: the same as x except activation is not applied
        - w: A numpy nd array of weights connecting this layer to the previous layer

        Returns:
        - dcdx: gradient with respect to x(1 x k)
        - dcdw: gradient with respect to w
        - dcdb: gradient with respect to b
        """

        rd = self.relu_derivative(unactivated)

        # Clip values to avoid extremely large numbers
        dprev_clipped = np.clip(dprev, -1e15, 1e15)
        w_clipped = np.clip(w, -1e15, 1e15)

        dot_product = dprev_clipped.dot(w_clipped.T)

        # Handle potential NaN or inf values
        dot_product = np.nan_to_num(dot_product, nan=0.0, posinf=1e15, neginf=-1e15)

        dcdx = dot_product * rd

        # Clip final result
        dcdx = np.clip(dcdx, -1e15, 1e15)

        dcdw = activated.T.dot(dprev_clipped)
        dcdw = np.clip(dcdw, -1e15, 1e15)
        dcdb = np.sum(dprev_clipped, axis=0, keepdims=True)

        return dcdx, dcdw, dcdb


    def relu_activation(self, x: np.ndarray):
        """
        Applies relu activation on an input

        Parameters:
        - x: A numpy nd array(1 x n)

        Returns:
        - activated_x: A numpy nd array(1xn)
        """

        activated_x = np.maximum(0, x)
        return activated_x


    def relu_derivative(self, x: np.ndarray):
        """
        Computes the derivative of the relu activation function.

        Parameters:
        - x: A numpy nd array

        Returns:
        - derivative: The derivative of relu applied to x.
        """

        mask = x > 0

        derivative = x * mask
        return derivative


    def create_fully_connected_weights(self, layer1_length: int, layer2_length: int):
        """
        Creates weights between two layers and initializes them to random values between 0 and 1
        The layers are assumed to be fully connected
        The column of the returned weights need to be multiplied by previous layer to get outputs of layer 2

        Parameters:
        - layer1_length
        - layer2_length

        Returns:
        - np array of shape m x n. m - length of layer 1, n - length of layer 2
        """

        m = layer1_length
        n = layer2_length

        weights = np.random.rand(m, n)
        return weights


    def create_layer(self, n: int):
        """
        Creates and returns a zero numpy array of shape 1 x n

        Parameters:
        - n amount of nodes in a layer
        """
        layer = np.zeros(n).reshape(1, -1)
        return layer

    def softmax_activation(self, x: np.ndarray):
        """
        Applies softmax activation on an input

        Parameters:
        - x: A numpy nd array(1 x n)

        Returns:
        - activated_x: A numpy nd array(1xn)
        """
        normalized_x = x - np.max(x)
        exps = np.exp(normalized_x)
        activated_x = exps / np.sum(exps)
        return activated_x


    def cross_entropy_cost(self, expected: np.ndarray, actual: np.ndarray):
        """
        Computes the cross entropy cost

        Parameters:
        - expected: A numpy nd array(1 x n)
        - actual: A numpy nd array(1 x n)

        Returns:
        - cost: float
        """

        epsilon = 1e-15
        actual = np.clip(actual, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)
        cost = -np.sum(expected * np.log(actual))
        return cost


    def train(self, epochs: int, X_train: np.ndarray, y_train: np.ndarray, learning_rate: float, batch_size: int = 20):
        """
        Trains the neural network

        Parameters:
        - epochs: number of epochs
        - X_train: numpy array of features
        - y_train: numpy array of targets
        - learning_rate: float
        """
        input_layer = self.create_layer(X_train.shape[1])
        hidden_layer1 = self.create_layer(64)
        hidden_layer2 = self.create_layer(64)
        output_layer = self.create_layer(10)

        weights1 = self.create_fully_connected_weights(input_layer.size, hidden_layer1.size)
        weights2 = self.create_fully_connected_weights(hidden_layer1.size, hidden_layer2.size)
        weights3 = self.create_fully_connected_weights(hidden_layer2.size, output_layer.size)

        bias1 = np.zeros((1, hidden_layer1.size))
        bias2 = np.zeros((1, hidden_layer2.size))
        bias3 = np.zeros((1, output_layer.size))

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            total_cost = 0

            weights1_sum = np.zeros_like(weights1)
            weights2_sum = np.zeros_like(weights2)
            weights3_sum = np.zeros_like(weights3)

            bias1_sum = np.zeros_like(bias1)
            bias2_sum = np.zeros_like(bias2)
            bias3_sum = np.zeros_like(bias3)
            # do forward and backward propagation for each input row
            for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):
                # forward
                input_layer = X_train[i].reshape(1, -1)
                hidden_layer1, hidden_layer_activated1 = self.forward(input_layer, weights1, bias1)
                hidden_layer2, hidden_layer_activated2 = self.forward(hidden_layer_activated1, weights2, bias2)
                output_layer, output_layer_activated = self.forward(hidden_layer_activated2, weights3, bias3)

                # apply softmax activation to output layer
                output_layer_activated = self.softmax_activation(output_layer)

                cost = self.cross_entropy_cost(y_train[i].reshape(1, -1), output_layer_activated)
                total_cost += cost

                # backward
                dcdl_output = output_layer_activated - y_train[i].reshape(1, -1)
                dcdl_hidden2, dcdw3, dcdb3 = self.backward(dcdl_output, hidden_layer_activated2, hidden_layer2, weights3)
                dcdl_hidden1, dcdw2, dcdb2 = self.backward(dcdl_hidden2, hidden_layer_activated1, hidden_layer1, weights2)
                dcdl_input, dcdw1, dcdb1 = self.backward(dcdl_hidden1, input_layer, input_layer, weights1)

                weights1_sum += dcdw1
                weights2_sum += dcdw2
                weights3_sum += dcdw3

                bias1_sum += dcdb1
                bias2_sum += dcdb2
                bias3_sum += dcdb3

                if i % batch_size == 0 or i == X_train.shape[0] - 1:
                    weights1 -= learning_rate * weights1_sum / batch_size
                    weights2 -= learning_rate * weights2_sum / batch_size
                    weights3 -= learning_rate * weights3_sum / batch_size

                    bias1 -= learning_rate * bias1_sum / batch_size
                    bias2 -= learning_rate * bias2_sum / batch_size
                    bias3 -= learning_rate * bias3_sum / batch_size

                    weights1_sum = np.zeros_like(weights1)
                    weights2_sum = np.zeros_like(weights2)
                    weights3_sum = np.zeros_like(weights3)

                    bias1_sum = np.zeros_like(bias1)
                    bias2_sum = np.zeros_like(bias2)
                    bias3_sum = np.zeros_like(bias3)

            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}, Cost: {total_cost / X_train.shape[0]}")
        self.weights = [weights1, weights2, weights3]
        self.biases = [bias1, bias2, bias3]

    def predict(self, x: np.ndarray):
        # do forward propagation
        layer = x
        output_layer = None
        for weights, bias in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            hidden_layer, hidden_layer_activated = self.forward(layer, weights, bias)
            layer = hidden_layer_activated
            output_layer = hidden_layer

        output_layer_activated = self.softmax_activation(output_layer)
        return output_layer_activated

    def calculate_accuracy(self, X_test, y_test):
        correct_predictions = 0
        total_predictions = len(y_test)

        for x, y_true in zip(X_test, y_test):
            # forward pass through the network
            prediction = self.predict(x)

            # get the predicted class (index of max value in output)
            predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction)
            true_class = np.argmax(y_true)

            if predicted_class == true_class:
                correct_predictions += 1

        accuracy = correct_predictions / total_predictions
        return accuracy

This is the training part
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

# loading the dataset. p.s. too much pain to use raw version, using this already premade instead
(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = mnist.load_data()

# one-hot encode train labels
train_y_encoded = np.zeros((train_y.shape[0], 10))
for i in range(train_y.shape[0]):
    train_y_encoded[i, train_y[i]] = 1

train_y = train_y_encoded

# One-hot encode test labels
test_y_encoded = np.zeros((test_y.shape[0], 10))
for i in range(test_y.shape[0]):
    test_y_encoded[i, test_y[i]] = 1

test_y = test_y_encoded

# divide all images by 255 so that all pixel values are between 0 and 1
train_X = train_X / 255
test_X = test_X / 255

# reshape the images to be 1D
train_X = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0], -1)
test_X = test_X.reshape(test_X.shape[0], -1)

nn = NN()

nn.train(30, train_X, train_y, 0.001, 128)

I would really appreciate any help

10% on MNIST is random guess accuracy. It could be that you're blowing up your weights due to exploding gradients, high learning rate etc.
